# Listing cities from coordinates

Tags: r

I have a table of coordinates, and I need to list the corresponding cities using R. Any recommendations?

I have tried:

```
library(maps)

cities <- dataset
cities[is.na(cities)] <- 0
map.where("world", dataset$lon, dataset$lat, fill==TRUE)
```

Comment: "Reverse geocoding" is the name of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick solution to reverse geocoding in `ggmap`:

```
library(ggmap)

> coords
        lon      lat
1  37.61730 55.75583
2 116.40739 39.90421
3 -77.03687 38.90719

res <- lapply(with(coords, paste(lat, lon, sep = ",")), geocode, output = "more")


> transform(coords, city = sapply(res, "[[", "locality"))
        lon      lat       city
1  37.61730 55.75583     Moskva
2 116.40739 39.90421    Beijing
3 -77.03687 38.90719 Washington
```

Comment: If you want to geocode locations , it's simply 'geocode(x)' where x is a character vector containing the cities you want to geocode .  For example 'x <- c("moscow", "New York" , "Beijing")'.   If my answer helped you please mark it correct .